# Summarize_if and concatenate ids that were sum

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the following code:

```
d <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:3, .Label = c("k141_20041_1", 
    "k141_27047_2", "k141_70_3"), class = "factor"), phylum = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Firmicutes", class = "factor"), class = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacillales", class = "factor"), order = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacilli", class = "factor"), family = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacillaceae", class = "factor"), genus = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacillus", class = "factor"), species = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bacillus subtilis", "unknown"), class = "factor"), 
        SampleA = c(0, 0, 0), SampleB = c(0, 0, 0), SampleCtrl = c(3.98888888888889, 
        11.5555555555556, 3.35978835978836)), .Names = c("Gene", 
    "phylum", "class", "order", "family", "genus", "species", "SampleA", 
    "SampleB", "SampleCtrl"), row.names = c(21918L, 40410L, 40857L
    ), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the output dataframe:

```
Gene     phylum      class   order      family    genus           species SampleA SampleB
k141_20041_1 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0
k141_27047_2 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0
k141_70_3 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus           unknown       0       0
  SampleCtrl
  3.99
 11.56
  3.36
```

I'm summarizing as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
d%>%
group_by(phylum,class,order,family,genus, species)%>%
summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)    

      phylum      class   order      family    genus           species SampleA SampleB SampleCtrl
      <fctr>     <fctr>  <fctr>      <fctr>   <fctr>            <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0   15.54444
2 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus           unknown       0       0    3.35979
```

I would like to add one column and concatenate the Genes that were summarized. For example it would look like this:

```
    phylum      class   order      family    genus           species SampleA SampleB SampleCtrl Gene
      <fctr>     <fctr>  <fctr>      <fctr>   <fctr>            <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis       0       0   15.54444  k141_20041_1,k141_27047_2
2 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus           unknown       0       0    3.35979 k141_70_3
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to use `toString` to paste the genes and then group on the same columns, including the new Gene column so that `summarise` includes it in the final table.

```
library(dplyr)
d%>%
  group_by(phylum,class,order,family,genus, species)%>%
  mutate(Gene=toString(Gene))%>%
  group_by(phylum,class,order,family,genus, species,Gene)%>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)   
      phylum      class   order      family    genus           species                       Gene SampleA SampleB SampleCtrl
      <fctr>     <fctr>  <fctr>      <fctr>   <fctr>            <fctr>                      <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus Bacillus subtilis k141_20041_1, k141_27047_2       0       0  15.544444
2 Firmicutes Bacillales Bacilli Bacillaceae Bacillus           unknown                  k141_70_3       0       0   3.359788
```

Comment: Why do you need to regroup with Gene? shouldn't a `mutate(Gene = toString)` after the `summarise_if` do the trick?

Comment: @Sotos No, it disappears in the `summarise_if``. If it was a normal `summarise`, you could also add max(Gene) to include it.

Comment: Yeah, missed the `_if` there in summarise

Comment: @Thanks for  posting a clear question with `dput`, your attempt and the desired result.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Not  sure how: I tried `d%>%
  group_by(phylum,class,order,family,genus, species,Gene=toString(Gene))%>%  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) `, but the gene column includes all genes.